# Ng2-datepicker 404 Not Found latest RC

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap, ng2-datepicker

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {routing} from './app.routing';
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import {HeroService}    from './hero.service';
import {HeroesComponent} from './heroes.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';

import './rxjs-extensions';
import {HeroSearchComponent} from './hero-search.component';

import { DatePicker } from 'ng2-datepicker/ng2-datepicker';



@NgModule({
  imports:[ DatePicker,BrowserModule,FormsModule,routing,HttpModule,InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)],
  declarations:[ AppComponent,HeroSearchComponent,HeroDetailComponent,HeroesComponent,DashboardComponent ],
  providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap:[ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" media="all">

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

hero.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
 moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-heroes',
  template: `
<div>
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" [expanded]="true"></datepicker>

Selected date is: {{ date }}

</div>  


  `,
 })
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  date;



  constructor(private heroService:HeroService,private router:Router){

    alert(this.date);

  } 

}
```

[Error Console for date picker 4o4 ng2-datepicker NOT FOUND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG9Wz.png)

I already done npm install ng2-datepicker --save .Is there something wrong?Please Help Me. I know it's a simple but i don't know why it's not found ng2-datepicker

Systemjs.config

```
    /**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
       moment: 'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
      "ng2-datepicker": '../node_modules/ng2-datepicker',
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {

      'ng2-datepicker': { main: './ng2-datepicker.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js',

      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: please share your systemjs.config.js

Comment: Should i Need TO add bundle for translate. How can i find Bundle?

Answer (score 1):

this is what i had to do i had to npm install ng2-datepicker.. then I had to npm install moment, then npm install ng2-slimscroll then i had to go into my systemjs.config.js and add these to my path and packages everything works as it should this is my full systemconfig

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
      'ng2-datepicker': 'npm:ng2-datepicker', 
      'moment': 'npm:moment', 
      'ng2-slimscroll': 'npm:ng2-slimscroll', 

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      'ng2-datepicker': {  main: './ng2-datepicker.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'ng2-slimscroll': {  main: './ng2-slimscroll.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      'moment': {  main: './moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your systemjs.config.js, add below block-

```
var map = {
...
"ng2-datepicker": '../node_modules/ng2-datepicker'
};
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
...
'ng2-datepicker': {  main: './ng2-datepicker.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
...
};
```

Comment: map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      
      "ng2-datepicker": '../node_modules/ng2-datepicker'   ,
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',

Comment: packages: {
       'ng2-datepicker': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js',
       
      },

Comment: Try using this-`'ng2-datepicker': {  main: './ng2-datepicker.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },`

Comment: Sir,Error status change like this.                                                                      --(index):20 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/moment(…)

Comment: Try loading moment.js in your index.html like this- `<script src="node_modules/moment/moment.js"></script>`

Comment: Error status change again Sir                                                                       -(index):21 Error: Error: Unexpected directive 'DatePickerComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'(…)                                                      -i will edit my post  System.config.js again.Please check.